# PostgreSQL Most Recent Date Based On 2 IDs

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

So I have a table that looks something like this:

```
+-------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| Purchase ID | Detail ID | Status ID | Status Date |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
|       20532 |         1 |         1 | 2018-04-18  |
|       20532 |         1 |         3 | 2018-05-18  |
|       20145 |         1 |         1 | 2018-04-18  |
|       20145 |         2 |         4 | 2018-06-18  |
|       20145 |         2 |         4 | 2018-07-18  |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
```

My goal is to get the status ID from the most recent date for each Purchase ID and Detail ID, so in this case:

```
+-------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| Purchase ID | Detail ID | Status ID | Status Date |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
|       20532 |         1 |         3 | 2018-05-18  |
|       20145 |         1 |         1 | 2018-04-18  |
|       20145 |         2 |         4 | 2018-07-18  |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
```

I've tried getting the MAX date, but what I need is the Status ID and it's forcing me to group by the Status ID which defeats the purpose.  Other things I've tried gave me duplicate detail IDs for the same Purchase ID's.

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using window functions?

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by detailid order by statusdate desc) as seqnum_d,
             row_number() over (partition by statusid order by statusdate desc) as seqnum_s
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum_d = 1 or seqnum_s = 1;
```

EDIT:

If you want the most recent date per *combination*, you can use `partition by detailid, statusid`.  Another method is:

```
select distinct on (detailid, statusid) t.*
from t
order by detailid, statusid, statusdate desc;
```

`distinct on` is often faster than other methods.  And, it can take advantage of an index on `(detailid, statusid, statusdate)`.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed, the only difference I had to make was to change seqnum_d to (PARTITION BY purchaseid, detailid ORDER BY statusdate DESC).

Comment: @Tbot . . . That makes sense.  I thought you wanted each individually.